# Prolog partial rule matching

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to partially match rule in prolog ?

`a( b ) :- k(c),k( d ).`
`a( e ) :- k(g),k( d ).`

So knowing that `k(d):-true.` is it somehow possible to obtain b & e ?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: If you're asking to derive, for example, `a(b)` given that `k(d)` is true, but `k(c)` is false, you can't with the rules you're showing. You might be able to create a meta-interpreter of the rules to determine that, however.

Comment: @lurker That is exactly what i want ;| ok then i guess prolog isn't the best choice

Comment: I didn't say Prolog's not the best choice. ;) You can write a rule verifier in Prolog.

Comment: hmm , what about the other way around - is it possible to get all `a( )` rules and all their right side elements , and check if one is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did what i wanted to and it goes like this (swi_prolog) where **rule** is the name of rules to check

```
true_check([_,H,B]):-
    call(H)->true;B=..L,true_check(L).
true_check([B]) :-
    call(B)->true;false.

possible(Rule):-
   current_predicate(rule,Head),
   clause(Head,B),
   B=..I,
   true_check(I),
   Head=..[_,Rule].
```